# Adapting Tensorflow2 code - simulating a reaction-diffusion soliton to include 3 velocity fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, physics, velocity

I am trying to adapt a program that simulates a reaction-diffusion soliton made up of substrates X, Y and G. The program includes Navier-Stokes equation to give vortical motion to the substrates.

At present the code gives rotational/vortical motion to the X, Y and G in terms of velocity field u and v, representing velocity vector in x and y directions in this 2D simulation. The z axis being X, Y and G concentration potentials.

In 1D it looks like this:

[image]

I want to change the code so that substrates X, Y and G each have separate velocities (not just the same ones). I.e. X velocity field --> u_X and v_X etc. Please can someone help me adapt the code?

Here is what I have done so far:

Original [code](https://github.com/frostburn/tf2-model-g): and [theory](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g/blob/master/docs/overview.pdf) the code is based on.

The code being altered for separate velocity fields is shown [here](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g-velocity).

The code is run with e.g.:  `python3 render_video.py ~/tf2-model-g/nucleation_and_motion_in_fluid_2D.mp4 --params params/nucleation_and_motion_in_fluid_2D.yaml`

Firstly, I changed [fluid_model_g________1st_attempt.py#L69](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g-velocity/blob/master/fluid_model_g________1st_attempt.py#L69) with:

```
    elif self.dims == 2:
        #self.u = tf.constant(u[0], 'float64') # original 2 lines
        #self.v = tf.constant(u[1], 'float64')

        #BJD adaptions - 6 lines below 9.6.2021 
        self.u_X = tf.constant(u[0], 'float64')
        self.v_X = tf.constant(u[1], 'float64')
        self.u_Y = tf.constant(u[2], 'float64')
        self.v_Y = tf.constant(u[3], 'float64')
        self.u_G = tf.constant(u[4], 'float64')
        self.v_G = tf.constant(u[5], 'float64')
```

and `def diffusion_advection_integrator` @ [fluid_model_g________1st_attempt.py#L159](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g-velocity/blob/master/fluid_model_g________1st_attempt.py#L159) :

```
        def diffusion_advection_integrator(G, X, Y, u_X, v_X, u_Y, v_Y, u_G, v_G, divergence1,divergence2, divergence3): # BJD original 10.6.2021
        
            f_G = self.fft(tf.cast(G, 'complex128'))
            f_X = self.fft(tf.cast(X, 'complex128'))
            f_Y = self.fft(tf.cast(Y, 'complex128'))

            f_G *= decay_G
            f_X *= decay_X
            f_Y *= decay_Y

            G = tf.cast(self.ifft(f_G), 'float64')
            X = tf.cast(self.ifft(f_X), 'float64')
            Y = tf.cast(self.ifft(f_Y), 'float64')

            G_dx = tf.cast(self.ifft(f_G * self.kernel_dx), 'float64')
            G_dy = tf.cast(self.ifft(f_G * self.kernel_dy), 'float64')
            X_dx = tf.cast(self.ifft(f_X * self.kernel_dx), 'float64')
            X_dy = tf.cast(self.ifft(f_X * self.kernel_dy), 'float64')
            Y_dx = tf.cast(self.ifft(f_Y * self.kernel_dx), 'float64')
            Y_dy = tf.cast(self.ifft(f_Y * self.kernel_dy), 'float64')

            #G -= (u*G_dx + v*G_dy + G*divergence) * self.dt # BJD original
            G -= (u_G*G_dx + v_G*G_dy + G*divergence1) * self.dt # BJD change 10.6.2021
            #X -= (u*X_dx + v*X_dy + X*divergence) * self.dt # BJD original
            #Y -= (u*Y_dx + v*Y_dy + Y*divergence) * self.dt # BJD original
            X -= (u_X*X_dx + v_X*X_dy + X*divergence2) * self.dt # BJD change 10.6.2021
            Y -= (u_Y*Y_dx + v_Y*Y_dy + Y*divergence3) * self.dt # BJD change 10.6.2021

            return G, X, Y
```

original code is shown here: [fluid_model_g.py#L57](https://github.com/frostburn/tf2-model-g/blob/master/fluid_model_g.py#L57) and here: [fluid_model_g.py#L119](https://github.com/frostburn/tf2-model-g/blob/master/fluid_model_g.py#L119)

3 separate densities were included in the new code: @ [fluid_model_g________1st_attempt.py#L297](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g-velocity/blob/master/fluid_model_g________1st_attempt.py#L297)

```
    # rho = tf.math.log(self.params['base-density'] + density_of_reactants) # BJD original here
    rho1 = tf.math.log(self.params['base-density1'] + density_of_reactants) # BJD added 10.6.2021
    rho2 = tf.math.log(self.params['base-density2'] + density_of_reactants) # BJD added 10.6.2021
    rho3 = tf.math.log(self.params['base-density3'] + density_of_reactants) # BJD added 10.6.2021
```

and `base-density1`, `base-density2` and `base-density3` were added to the [`yaml`](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g-velocity/blob/master/params/nucleation_and_motion_in_fluid_2D___1st_attempt.yaml#L25) file:

```
#base-density: 35.0 ~ BJD original here
base-density1: 35.0 # BJD added 10.6.2021
base-density2: 36.0 # BJD added 10.6.2021
base-density3: 37.0 # BJD added 10.6.2021
```

At the bottom of [`fluid_model_g.py`](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g-velocity/blob/master/fluid_model_g________1st_attempt.py#L301), these lines were changed:

```
    if self.dims == 2:
        #u, v = self.u, self.v  # Store unintegrated flow so that we're on the same timestep --- BJD original line 9.6.2021
        u_X, v_X = self.u_X, self.v_X  # Store unintegrated flow so that we're on the same timestep --- BJD added 9.6.2021
        u_Y, v_Y = self.u_Y, self.v_Y  # Store unintegrated flow so that we're on the same timestep --- BJD added 9.6.2021
        u_G, v_G = self.u_G, self.v_G  # Store unintegrated flow so that we're on the same timestep --- BJD added 9.6.2021

        #self.u, self.v, divergence = self.flow_integrator(rho, self.u, self.v) -BJD original line 9.6.2021
        self.u_X, self.v_X, divergence1 = self.flow_integrator(rho1, self.u_X, self.v_X) #--- BJD added 9.6.2021
        self.u_Y, self.v_Y, divergence2 = self.flow_integrator(rho2, self.u_Y, self.v_Y) #--- BJD added 9.6.2021
        self.u_G, self.v_G, divergence3 = self.flow_integrator(rho3, self.u_G, self.v_G) #--- BJD added 9.6.2021

        #self.G, self.X, self.Y = self.diffusion_advection_integrator(self.G, self.X, self.Y, u, v, divergence) # BJD original line 10.6.2021
        self.G, self.X, self.Y = self.diffusion_advection_integrator(self.G, self.X, self.Y, u_X, v_X, u_Y, v_Y, u_G, v_G, divergence1, divergence2, divergence3) #--- BJD added 10.6.2021
```

Looking at line: [fluid_model_g________1st_attempt.py#L47](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g-velocity/blob/master/fluid_model_g________1st_attempt.py#L47)

```
    #super().__init__(dx, dt, concentration_G.shape) # BJD original 13.6.2021
    super().__init__(dx, dt, concentration_G.shape, concentration_X.shape, concentration_Y.shape) # BJD change 13.6.2021
```

I started to make changes in file `pde_solver.py` @ [pde_solver________1st_attempt.py#L10](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g-velocity/blob/master/pde_solver________1st_attempt.py#L10) and [pde_solver________1st_attempt.py#L16](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g-velocity/blob/master/pde_solver________1st_attempt.py#L16) and [pde_solver________1st_attempt.py#L55](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g-velocity/blob/master/pde_solver________1st_attempt.py#L55); [pde_solver________1st_attempt.py#L81](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g-velocity/blob/master/pde_solver________1st_attempt.py#L81) and [pde_solver________1st_attempt.py#L99](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g-velocity/blob/master/pde_solver________1st_attempt.py#L99)

```
def __init__(self, dx, dt, shape_G, shape_X, shape_Y): # shape_G, shape_X, shape_Y ::: put in by David J. 13.6.2021
    self.dx = dx
    self.dt = dt
    self.t = 0

    omega = []
    for s in shape_G:  # shape_G, shape_X, shape_Y, i.e. 3 for loops made; original 1 for loop ::: put in by David J. 13.6.2021
        wave_numbers = np.arange(s)
        wave_numbers -= s * (2*wave_numbers > s)  # Deal with TensorFlow's uncentered FFT
        expected_span = 2*np.pi
        actual_span = s*dx
        omega.append(wave_numbers * expected_span / actual_span)
    for s in shape_X:
        wave_numbers = np.arange(s)
        wave_numbers -= s * (2*wave_numbers > s)  # Deal with TensorFlow's uncentered FFT
        expected_span = 2*np.pi
        actual_span = s*dx
        omega.append(wave_numbers * expected_span / actual_span)
    for s in shape_Y:
        wave_numbers = np.arange(s)
        wave_numbers -= s * (2*wave_numbers > s)  # Deal with TensorFlow's uncentered FFT
        expected_span = 2*np.pi
        actual_span = s*dx
        omega.append(wave_numbers * expected_span / actual_span)
    self.omega = np.meshgrid(*omega, indexing='ij')
    self.dims = len(shape_G) + len(shape_X) + len(shape_Y)
    # The naming is a bit off. These are not actual 'kernels'.
    # They are discrete fourier transforms of the periodic versions of the kernels
    if self.dims == 1:
        self.fft = tf.signal.fft
        self.ifft = tf.signal.ifft
        self.omega_x = self.omega[0]
    elif self.dims == 2:
        self.fft = tf.signal.fft2d
        self.ifft = tf.signal.ifft2d

        self.omega_x = self.omega[0]
        self.omega_y = self.omega[1]
    elif self.dims == 3:
        self.fft = tf.signal.fft3d
        self.ifft = tf.signal.ifft3d

        self.omega_x = self.omega[0]
        self.omega_y = self.omega[1]
        self.omega_z = self.omega[2]
    elif self.dims == 6: # With 3 fluids 2 dimensions # :::: put in by David J. 13.6.2021
        self.fft = tf.signal.fft2d
        self.ifft = tf.signal.ifft2d

        self.omega_x = self.omega[0]
        self.omega_y = self.omega[1]
        self.omega_X_x = self.omega[2]
        self.omega_X_y = self.omega[3]
        self.omega_Y_x = self.omega[4]
        self.omega_Y_y = self.omega[5]
    else:
        raise ValueError('{} dimensions not supported'.format(self.dims))


class PDESolverDx(PDESolver):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.dims == 1:
            self.kernel_dx = tf.constant(1j * self.omega_x, 'complex128')
        elif self.dims == 2:
            self.kernel_dx = tf.constant(1j * self.omega_x, 'complex128')
            self.kernel_dy = tf.constant(1j * self.omega_y, 'complex128')
        elif self.dims == 3:
            self.kernel_dx = tf.constant(1j * self.omega_x, 'complex128')
            self.kernel_dy = tf.constant(1j * self.omega_y, 'complex128')
            self.kernel_dz = tf.constant(1j * self.omega_z, 'complex128')
        elif self.dims == 6:   # :::: put in by David J. 13.6.2021
            self.kernel_dx = tf.constant(1j * self.omega_x, 'complex128')
            self.kernel_dy = tf.constant(1j * self.omega_y, 'complex128')
            self.kernel_X_dx = tf.constant(1j * self.omega_X_x, 'complex128')
            self.kernel_X_dy = tf.constant(1j * self.omega_X_y, 'complex128')
            self.kernel_Y_dx = tf.constant(1j * self.omega_Y_x, 'complex128')
            self.kernel_Y_dy = tf.constant(1j * self.omega_Y_y, 'complex128')


class PDESolverDx2(PDESolverDx):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.dims == 1:
            self.kernel_laplacian = tf.constant(-self.omega_x**2, 'complex128')
        elif self.dims == 2:
            self.kernel_laplacian = tf.constant(-(self.omega_x**2 + self.omega_y**2), 'complex128')
        elif self.dims == 3:
            self.kernel_laplacian = tf.constant(-(self.omega_x**2 + self.omega_y**2 + self.omega_z**2), 'complex128')
        elif self.dims == 6:  # :::: put in by David J. 13.6.2021
            self.kernel_laplacian = tf.constant(-(self.omega_x**2 + self.omega_y**2), 'complex128')
            self.kernel_laplacian_X = tf.constant(-(self.omega_X_x**2 + self.omega_X_y**2), 'complex128')
            self.kernel_laplacian_Y = tf.constant(-(self.omega_Y_x**2 + self.omega_Y_y**2), 'complex128')
```

The original is shown here: [pde_solver.py#L10](https://github.com/frostburn/tf2-model-g/blob/master/pde_solver.py#L10)

This is as far as I got! Can anyone help me solve this program change for including separate velocity fields for X, Y and G substrates?

Comment: @p._phidot_ dt is shown here: [fluid_model_g.py#L159](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g-velocity/blob/master/fluid_model_g.py#L159) and [fluid_model_g.py#L347](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g-velocity/blob/master/fluid_model_g.py#L347). Also here: [render_video.py#L64](https://github.com/bjdarrer/tf2-model-g-velocity/blob/master/render_video.py#L64)

Comment: if i'm not mistaken.. u r referring to equation 18 in the theory (tell me if the assumption IS wrong). Just for "velocity fields for X", is the available variables (dx dy dz dt for X) sufficient to define 'u'?

Comment: @p._phidot_ Equation (18) is correct and the code simulation works in the [original](https://github.com/frostburn/tf2-model-g) with only one velocity field of u and v. Yes, I think variables (dx dy dz dt for X) are sufficient to define 'u'. X comes from A and B in [yaml](https://github.com/frostburn/tf2-model-g/blob/master/params/nucleation_and_motion_in_fluid_2D.yaml) file. The theory of this Model G is similar to the [Brusselator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brusselator).

Comment: @p._phidot_ to define `u` , you also need `base-density` shown in [yaml](https://github.com/frostburn/tf2-model-g/blob/master/params/nucleation_and_motion_in_fluid_2D.yaml#L19) file.

Comment: @p._phidot_  The guy who wrote the code advised me: "Instead of combining everything into "density_of_reactants" you would keep them them separate and have velocity fields for each reactants as you already suggested. I would spell them u_X, v_X etc.
If you assume that the velocity fields do not interact directly then you don't need to modify the flow_integrator. Just pass in different rho calculated from individual reactants."

Comment: (regardless of who is code author) That is theoretically good idea.. passing rho is better.. | but still the question stands.. Is the available variables sufficient to define the relations? If yes.. write f(rho) for that and proceed. If no, settle the relation (algo) 1st before proceeding to the code. | As it stands, Imho "velocity fields for X, Y and G substrates" IS already separated in theory .

Comment: @p._phidot_  Thank you very much, you got me thinking. I think I may have solved with minimal change to the code! By including a `for loop` and `if statements` [here](https://github.com/frostburn/tf2-model-g/blob/master/fluid_model_g.py#L268), and using a different `rho` for each substrate: X, Y and G.

Comment: Glad it helps.. [ write a bit on that and post as an answer.. (the question is already written insightfully.. ) ] hope that it helps [algorithm],  [physics] & others in the future.. ] ( :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by the following procedure. 3 separate functions of `diffusion_advection_integrator()` where made:

```
def diffusion_advection_integrator1(G, u, v, divergence): 
def diffusion_advection_integrator2(X, u, v, divergence): 
def diffusion_advection_integrator3(Y, u, v, divergence):
```

Each one only containing the `G`, `X` or `Y` components. Original code [here](https://github.com/frostburn/tf2-model-g/blob/master/fluid_model_g.py#L119).

Then the remaining code was updated as follows:

```
    self.reaction_integrator = tf.function(reaction_integrator_curried)
    self.flow_integrator = tf.function(flow_integrator)
    #self.diffusion_advection_integrator = tf.function(diffusion_advection_integrator) # original
    self.diffusion_advection_integrator1 = tf.function(diffusion_advection_integrator1) # BJD added 25.6.2021
    self.diffusion_advection_integrator2 = tf.function(diffusion_advection_integrator2) # BJD added 25.6.2021
    self.diffusion_advection_integrator3 = tf.function(diffusion_advection_integrator3) # BJD added 25.6.2021

def step(self):
    self.G, self.X, self.Y = self.reaction_integrator(self.G, self.X, self.Y)
    density_of_reactants = (
        self.params['density_G'] * self.G +
        self.params['density_X'] * self.X +
        self.params['density_Y'] * self.Y
    )

    if self.dims == 2:
        u, v = self.u, self.v  # Store unintegrated flow so that we're on the same timestep

        rho = tf.math.log(35.0 + density_of_reactants) # rho defined for self.G
        self.u, self.v, divergence = self.flow_integrator(rho, self.u, self.v)
        self.G = self.diffusion_advection_integrator1(self.G, u, v, divergence) # G calculated

        rho = tf.math.log(36.0 + density_of_reactants) # rho defined for self.X
        self.u, self.v, divergence = self.flow_integrator(rho, self.u, self.v)
        self.X = self.diffusion_advection_integrator2(self.X, u, v, divergence) # X calculated
                
        rho = tf.math.log(37.0 + density_of_reactants) # rho defined for self.Y
        self.u, self.v, divergence = self.flow_integrator(rho, self.u, self.v)
        self.Y = self.diffusion_advection_integrator3(self.Y, u, v, divergence) # Y calculated
```

Where the original code for the above part is shown [here](https://github.com/frostburn/tf2-model-g/blob/master/fluid_model_g.py#L256).

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, an answer would seem to be like the following, by just simply redefining a different `rho` (pressure term) for each `G`, `X`, and `Y`. Where, the velocity fields `u` and `v`, are redefined each time:

```
def step(self):
    self.G, self.X, self.Y = self.reaction_integrator(self.G, self.X, self.Y)
    density_of_reactants = (
        self.params['density_G'] * self.G +
        self.params['density_X'] * self.X +
        self.params['density_Y'] * self.Y
    )

    if self.dims == 2:
        u, v = self.u, self.v  # Store unintegrated flow so that we're on the same timestep

        rho = tf.math.log(35.0 + density_of_reactants) # rho defined for self.G
        self.u, self.v, divergence = self.flow_integrator(rho, self.u, self.v)
        self.G = self.diffusion_advection_integrator(self.G, self.X, self.Y, u, v, divergence) # G calculated

        rho = tf.math.log(36.0 + density_of_reactants) # rho defined for self.X
        self.u, self.v, divergence = self.flow_integrator(rho, self.u, self.v)
        self.X = self.diffusion_advection_integrator(self.G, self.X, self.Y, u, v, divergence) # X calculated
                
        rho = tf.math.log(37.0 + density_of_reactants) # rho defined for self.Y
        self.u, self.v, divergence = self.flow_integrator(rho, self.u, self.v)
        self.Y = self.diffusion_advection_integrator(self.G, self.X, self.Y, u, v, divergence) # Y calculated
```

Where original code is [here](https://github.com/frostburn/tf2-model-g/blob/master/fluid_model_g.py#L267).

However, this gives error message:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
in user code:

    /home/brendan/software/tf2-model-g-velocity/fluid_model_g.py:122 diffusion_advection_integrator  *
        f_X = self.fft(tf.cast(X, 'complex128'))
    /home/brendan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper  **
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/brendan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:920 cast
        x = ops.convert_to_tensor(x, name="x")
    /home/brendan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1499 convert_to_tensor
        ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    /home/brendan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:1502 _autopacking_conversion_function
        return _autopacking_helper(v, dtype, name or "packed")
    /home/brendan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:1438 _autopacking_helper
        return gen_array_ops.pack(elems_as_tensors, name=scope)
    /home/brendan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py:6476 pack
        _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
    /home/brendan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:742 _apply_op_helper
        op = g._create_op_internal(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None,
    /home/brendan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:591 _create_op_internal
        return super(FuncGraph, self)._create_op_internal(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    /home/brendan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:3477 _create_op_internal
        ret = Operation(
    /home/brendan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1974 __init__
        self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph, node_def, inputs,
    /home/brendan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1815 _create_c_op
        raise ValueError(str(e))

    ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 3 and 2
        From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for '{{node Cast_1/x}} = Pack[N=3, T=DT_DOUBLE, axis=0](X, X_1, X_2)' with input shapes: [3,426,240], [426,240], [426,240].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/tmp/tmp10_g9n1p.py", line 15, in tf__diffusion_advection_integrator
    f_X = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).fft, (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).cast, (ag__.ld(X), 'complex128'), None, fscope),), None, fscope)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/home/brendan/software/tf2-model-g-velocity/fluid_model_g.py", line 282, in step
    self.Y = self.diffusion_advection_integrator(self.G, self.X, self.Y, u, v, divergence) # Y calculated
  File "/home/brendan/software/tf2-model-g-velocity/render_video.py", line 78, in nucleation_and_motion_in_G_gradient_fluid_2D
    fluid_model_g.step()
  File "/home/brendan/software/tf2-model-g-velocity/render_video.py", line 292, in <module>
    episodes[args.episode](writer, args)
```

It appears the `Shapes must be equal rank`, so that:

```
self.Y = self.diffusion_advection_integrator(self.G, self.X, self.Y, u, v, divergence) # Y calculated
```

has to be:

```
self.G, self.X, self.Y = self.diffusion_advection_integrator(self.G, self.X, self.Y, u, v, divergence)
```